# Javascript / jQuery promises, handling variable amount of promises in a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Hello: I have a tree of terms that can contain up to 3 levels. I have a function "getTerms" that returns a list of items in the tree as a jQuery deferred. Then, I have a loop that is something like this:

```
getTerms().then(function(t0) {

  for (var i = 0; i < t0.length; i++)
  {
     t0[i]["children"] = [];
     allTerms.push(t0[i]);
     getTerms(t0[i]).then(function(t1) {

           for (var j = 0; j < t1.length; j++)
           {
               // process t1 items the same as t0...
           } 
     });

  }
});
```

At the end, I have a hierarchy that will look like a tree, with t0 items being in the first level, t1 in the second, and t2 in the 3rd. This hierarchy is stored in the variable allTerms.

The issue is I still have no real way to tell when traversal is completed. I know that I can create an array of promises and add them but the issue is that I have a variable number of terms each spinning off async calls at various levels of the tree and, at any time the array of promises could hit zero while awaiting a callback with more data.

I look forward to your advice on solving this problem. Thanks.